# Metamask+Remix gives different gas than Web3.js+Infura

Tags: remix, metamask, infura

I have one transaction, that can be executed with 2 different ways:
   - Remix with Metamask wallet
   - Web3.js with Infura network

In both ways, I am connected to Rinkeby network.

The Gas is different, though the same input data is used. Why is that happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the initial state is also the same? The same transaction may result in different gas usages depending on the contract state.

Comment: What does the function do? How do you know the gas was different? two transaction or with estimateGas. How much is the difference?

Comment: I have checked the GAS consumption through remix-debuger in both cases. In the case of Web3.js with Infura, i have fewer OpCodes.